# How would you create a dynamic visualization with two hierarchical categories?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a visualization of films data, where you can query the information based on certain things (like their rating), and then show the movies in chronological order (the plan is to have different timeframes or periods to be selected, and organization like by quarter, by year, etc):

1. Movies should be bundled by their genre
2. I want to show the icons to represent when they were released (but it could be any other time event I guess).

I've been able to get it more or less by having hidden ranges doing a lot of calculations. But how would you do this without using any "helper" ranges to make calculations? (or at least the minimal possible)

Appreciate any suggestions!

Here's [the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7U0-Qv1kHk9oR_68rju7qCzMGArxG_bsUJVM3LdLeM/edit#gid=1946045176) and target visual:
[image]

Thanks!

Update 1: Just quick update, that if there was simple way to create the "Genre" <> "Title" relationship with just one formula, then I can complete the rest with filters. In that case, how would you do this:

[image]

Update 2: brief description of research

I added in the tab "option 1" what my approach has been. I was able to get the output with a query function but without the formatting I need:

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as  is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Thanks Rubén. Just edited with the info and updated the example with the actual approach.

Comment: Try using conditional formatting.

Comment: What `hidden ranges` are you talking about? Would you consider using Apps Script [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: lamblichus, apologies! I ended up removing my previous scrappy solution. I was trying to avoid custom functions for this one. But I just got the solution!(although I added several approaches to the sheet). Will update the thread now but thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the final solution. Simplest way I could find (+added other options in the sheet):

```
=ArrayFormula({IF(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SORT({SPLIT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))&"|#%","|",0,0);FILTER({B2:B,A2:A},B2:B<>"")},1,1,2,1),"#%",""),"Select Col2")="",QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SORT({SPLIT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))&"|#%","|",0,0);FILTER({B2:B,A2:A},B2:B<>"")},1,1,2,1),"#%",""),"Select Col1"),""),QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SORT({SPLIT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))&"|#%","|",0,0);FILTER({B2:B,A2:A},B2:B<>"")},1,1,2,1),"#%",""),"Select Col2")})
```